# Serial communication RX size limitations

Tags: c, serial-communication

I can`t receive all of bytes what i send out. (Raspberry Pi 3B+ / Raspbian)

I tried to send 4000 bytes and receive only 960 bytes at 9600bit/s. When I increased speed, increased the received bytes. I tries to set VTIME and VMIN values in c_cc array, but not change everything.

How can I receive all of bytes?

```
transmitter:

char write_buffer[4000];    /* Buffer containing characters to write into port       */

        for(uint32_t i=0;i<4000;i++)
        {
            write_buffer[i] = i;
        }

        int  bytes_written  = 0;    /* Value for storing the number of bytes written to the port */ 

        bytes_written = write(fd,write_buffer,sizeof(write_buffer));/* use write() to send data to port                                            */
                                         /* "fd"                   - file descriptor pointing to the opened serial port */
                                         /* "write_buffer"         - address of the buffer containing data              */
                                         /* "sizeof(write_buffer)" - No of bytes to write                               */  
        printf("\n  %s written to ttyUSB0",write_buffer);
        printf("\n  %d Bytes written to ttyUSB0", bytes_written);
        printf("\n +----------------------------------+\n\n");

receiver:

/*------------------------------- Read data from serial port -----------------------------*/

        char read_buffer[4000];   /* Buffer to store the data received              */
        uint32_t  bytes_read = 0;    /* Number of bytes read by the read() system call */
        int i = 0;

        bytes_read = read(fd,&read_buffer,4000); /* Read the data                   */

        printf("\n\n  Bytes Rxed: %d", bytes_read); /* Print the number of bytes read */
        printf("\n\n  ");

        for(i=0;i<bytes_read;i++)    /*printing only the received characters*/
            printf("%c",read_buffer[i]);

        printf("\n +----------------------------------+\n\n\n");
```

output:

```
 +----------------------------------+
 |        Serial Port Write         |
 +----------------------------------+
  ttyUSB0 Opened Successfully 
  BaudRate = 9600 
  StopBits = 1 
  Parity   = none
   written to ttyUSB0
  4000 Bytes written to ttyUSB0
 +----------------------------------+



  Bytes Rxed: 960




 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������


 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������


 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������


 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~��������������������������������������������������������������
 +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: full code: https://pastebin.com/CmtHB2s7

Comment: termios: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html

Comment: Your receiver code doesn't appear to be in a loop? How are you expecting to receive more if you don't try again?

Comment: I want to receive all of datas in once time, this is just a testing

Comment: You want but you cannot. You specify maximum size to be read from descriptor, but the amount of data read does not depend on you. It is only guaranteed to be not greater than you specified. So in any case you need a loop

Comment: regarding: `int  bytes_written  = 0;     
bytes_written = write(fd,write_buffer,sizeof(write_buffer);`   the function: `write()` returns a `ssize_t` not a `int`

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n\n  Bytes Rxed: %d", bytes_read);` this will result in a compiler warning because `bytes_read` is unsigned and `'%d' is expecting a signed value.  However, the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t` not a `uint32_t`  The use of the output format specifier '%lu' or (better) '%zu'  should be used when printing a `ssize_t`

Comment: The `receiver` functionality should be calling `read()` in a loop and appending the results into a buffer until the returned value from `read()` is 0 ( or <0, indicating an error occurred )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` system call is not guaranteed to return the number of bytes requested. See [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) link for a full reference.

If `read` returns a non-negative value this value indicates the amount of bytes read, in your case 960 bytes.

To make sure that all bytes are read successfully you will need to put the call to `read` inside some form of loop. Perhaps something similar to this:

```
char buffer[4000 + 1]; /* +1 to leave space for null-terminator */

memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); /* Clear buffer */

size_t bytesToRead = 4000;
size_t bytesRead = 0;
while (bytesToRead > 0)
{
    const ssize_t retVal = read(fd, buffer + bytesRead, bytesToRead);
    if (retVal < 0)
    {
        /* Handle error */
    }

    const size_t bytes = (size_t) retVal;
    bytesRead += bytes;
    bytesToRead -= bytes;
}
```